# In Objective-C how to detect when iPhone and iPad are plugged in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I found a couple of tutorials online about detecting battery charge status changes, but what I need to detect is the second the iphone/ipad is plugged in. Not plugged in and then a charge update is sent out.

We need to prevent them from using our app if the battery is below 25% charge but if its plugged in then we need to allow them.

I used both of these, but neither notification gets fired when plugging in or unplugging.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    // tell the device that - my application is going to monitor Device Battery levels
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

    // schedule a timer to update the battery details
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateBatteryDetails)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(pluggedDetected)
                                                 name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(pluggedDetected)
                                                 name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you set `batteryMonitoringEnabled` to `YES`?

Comment: Oh yes I did call that.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't jump to conclusions and lash out. Also, this isn't a constructive comment. It makes perfect sense for our industry and the fact our app is an enterprise app.

Answer (score 3):

One problem with your code is that when you register for the notifications, you're passing in a selector that doesn't take any parameters. As [the docs for `NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDCIGGB) tell us:

> The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only
>   one argument (an instance of NSNotification).

Fixing that caused your code to work for me. Your method should look like this:

```
- (void)pluggedDetected:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //...
}
```

and your call to add the observer should look like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(pluggedDetected:)
                                             name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Note that the colon is an essential part of the selector name.

Given that you're using notifications to detect changes, I don't think you also need a timer to update the battery information -- just do that whenever a notification triggers your method.

Comment: Does this still work on iOS 8? I am using iOS 8 and I do what you said but I don't get the notification.

Comment: @leo2_uru Certainly `NSNotificationCenter` works in iOS 8 the same way it always has, and the docs for [UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification) don't indicate that anything has changed there. This isn't an old answer, and I'm pretty sure I tested against iOS 8. You might want to post your own question, including your code.

Comment: I have already done that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617434/uidevicebatterystatedidchangenotification-not-working-on-ios-8. Could you help me?