# UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, battery

I am working on a Cordova app and I need to know the initial state of the battery and get a notification when the state changes. I am using iOS 8 on an iPod Touch 5g.

I am getting the code from: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status/blob/master/src/ios/CDVBattery.m, so it should work...

I do this in AudioController.mm:

```
#import "AudioController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMusicPlayerController.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@implementation AudioController

+(void)initializeAudio
{

    //Battery state detection
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled == NO) {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateBatteryStatus:) name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateBatteryStatus:) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    }

    //Initial state

    UIDevice* currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    UIDeviceBatteryState currentState = [currentDevice batteryState];

    batteryState = NO; // UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown or UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged
    if ((currentState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) || (currentState == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull)) {
        batteryState = YES;
    }

    batteryLevel = 100 * [currentDevice batteryLevel];

}

//Battery detection

+ (void)updateBatteryStatus:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIDevice* currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    UIDeviceBatteryState currentState = [currentDevice batteryState];

    batteryState = NO; // UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown or UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged
    if ((currentState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) || (currentState == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull)) {
        batteryState = YES;
    }

    batteryLevel = 100 * [currentDevice batteryLevel];

}
```

In AudioController.h

```
@protocol AudioControllerDelegate;

@interface AudioController : NSObject 

+(void)initializeAudio;
+ (void)updateBatteryStatus:(NSNotification*)notification;

@end
```

I am getting the current state and the level but the method named updateBatteryStatus isn't called. Why is that?

PS: I am also using this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteChangeListenerCallback:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
```

to detect when the headphones are plugged in and this works.

PS2: I also have other methods there but those are the ones related to this problem.

Comment: If your application is starting with `batteryMonitoringEnabled`, you'll never add your `updateBatteryStatus` observer.

Comment: Do you say this because of that if? It is set... I could say that because of the debugger.

Comment: That is to avoid multiple sets of the observer because the init method could be called more than once.

Comment: Could you include the *actual* code? You've provided a couple snippets, but we can't tell what method(s) those are part of, or which class the methods belong to. Is the `-updateBatteryStatus:` action part of the same class that registers the notification handler?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will edit my question in seconds

Comment: If I change UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification  to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification the method is being called... But I always obtain true for the battery state, no matter if it is plugged or not.

Comment: Using UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, I keep checking the battery state/level when the notification occurs. It's weird too that the state doesn't change from the one that was calculated at the beginning (which is correctly calculated). I have 2 labels in the UI: one to know the new state and another one that tells me that it entered to the updateBatteryStatus... I can not check that using xCode :)